# Ionic 4 CLI can't generate service

Tags: ionic4, ionic-cli

In my ionic 4 project directory I am doing

`ionic g service api/login` to create service through cli. But I am getting

> [ERROR] type must be one of: component, directive, page, pipe, provider, tabs (not service)
>   Use the --help flag for more details.

then I seek for help `ionic g --help` so it giving me these examples

Examples:

```
$ ionic g
$ ionic g
$ ionic g component
$ ionic g directive
$ ionic g page
$ ionic g pipe
$ ionic g provider
$ ionic g tabs
$ ionic g component foo
$ ionic g page Login
$ ionic g page Detail --no-module
$ ionic g page About --constants
$ ionic g pipe MyFilterPipe
```

I cannot see service anywhere. How can I generate service an alternative way is also fine if you can suggest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the command argument “provider” instead of service:

```
ionic g provider your-service
```

The terms provider and service are synonymous here.

Comment: Are there any differences between providers and services?

Comment: ionic v7.1.5 suggests using `ionic generate service my-service`